# Wordpress pagination fade and continue reading toggle

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick, pagination, preventdefault

I want to load new content in a specific area of my website - works great. But after loading this all other jquery functionality isnt loaded. With the following code my "continue reading toggle" wants to do nothing. Is there a way to get around this?

```
/** =================================================================
* pagination fade
* ================================================================== */
$('#Pagination a').on('click', function(e){  

    var link = $(this).attr('href');  
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#inner').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500, 'linear', function(){

        $(this).load(link + ' #postcontent', function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500, 'linear');
        });
    });
});


/** =================================================================
continue reading toggle
================================================================== */

$('.continue-reading a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('p').next('.continue-reading_content').slideToggle("slow");

}).toggle(function() {
        $(this).text(continueReading_close);

    }, function() {
        $(this).text(continueReading_open);
    });
```

Here is a start fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ccj32/4/

---

Here is the final code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/** =================================================================
* pagination fade
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983244/simple-wordpress-ajax-pagination
* ================================================================== */

$(document).on('click', '#Pagination a', function(e){

    var link = $(this).attr('href');  
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#inner').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500, 'linear', function(){

        $(this).load(link + ' #postcontent', function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500, 'linear');
        });
    });
});


/** =================================================================
continue reading toggle
================================================================== */

$(document).on('click', '.continue-reading a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // old selectors
    //$(this).closest('p').next('.continue-reading_content').slideToggle("slow", function(){
    // $(this).closest('.entry-content').find('.continue-reading_content').slideToggle("slow", function(){

    // new selector to prevent if there is no <p> in content
    $(this).closest('.entry-content').children('.continue-reading_content').slideToggle("slow", function(){

        if ($('.continue-reading_content').is(':hidden'))
        {
            $('.continue-reading a').text(continueReading_open);    
        }
        else
        {
            $('.continue-reading a').text(continueReading_close);   
        }

    });

});
});
```

With event handlers set to the document, code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ccj32/7/

Comment: Are you dynamically loading '.continue-reading a' into the page?

Comment: Yeh, your event handlers should be set to the document. When you load new content in, it doesnt apply any event handlers to the new elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any content that is loaded into the page after the initial page load must have the event handlers set to the document like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.continue-reading a', function(){
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks wrxsti, with this after the $('#Pagination a').on('click', function(e){ - onclick works, but the page is jumping on top.

Comment: Is the e.preventDefault() still in the script? If you have a JSfiddle, it would be much easier to troubleshoot.  :)

Comment: No problem, when its ready edit your post with the link and I will check it out.   :)

Comment: I just looked over your fiddle, and I added a large spacer at the top. It doesn't seem to be jumping to the top of the page. Did I miss something? lol [FIDDLE with the spacer]http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/Ccj32/5/