# Use .load AJAX on multiple divs

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using .load() in wordpress for ajax pagination as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983244/simple-wordpress-ajax-pagination). However, it doesn't work when there are multiple loops on the same page with same class and ids. After click it loads the div of all loops in that particular div.

jquery

```
$('#pagination .page-numbers').live('click', function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#pagination').load(link + ' #pagination ul');
    $('#main').parent().append('<img class="opinions-loader-gif" src="http://example.com/images/AjaxLoader.gif" />');
    $('#main').animate({ opacity: 0.1 },500, function(){
        $(this).load(link + ' #main .container', function() {
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 },500);
            $('.opinions-loader-gif').remove();
        });
        $('#main').css('height', 'auto');
    });
    });
```

html

```
<!- loop1 -->
<div class="block">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pagination">
        <ul class="page-numbers">
            <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
            <li><a class="page-numbers" href="?paged1=2&paged2=1&paged3=1">2</a></li>
            <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="?paged1=2&paged2=1&paged3=1">Next »</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!- loop2 -->
<div class="block">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pagination">
        <ul class="page-numbers">
            <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
            <li><a class="page-numbers" href="?paged1=2&paged2=1&paged3=1">2</a></li>
            <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="?paged1=2&paged2=1&paged3=1">Next »</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!- loop3 -->
<div class="block">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pagination">
        <ul class="page-numbers">
            <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
            <li><a class="page-numbers" href="?paged1=2&paged2=1&paged3=1">2</a></li>
            <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="?paged1=2&paged2=1&paged3=1">Next »</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I get a `http://example.com/undefined 404 (Not Found)` everytime new content loads although everything loads fine.

Comment: In WordPress I'm not sure it is possible to have multiple loops each with their own pagination all on the same page.

Comment: Off topic: `live()` is deprecated.  Also, IDs must be unique.

Comment: @henrywright well, the pagination is working fine, I have tested it. Taken from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47261

Comment: @isherwood can you suggest a solution in this case. what if i give unique ids to loops, how do I alter the jquery?

Comment: what happens when you're viewing page 2 for one loop then click page 2 for a different loop?

Comment: @henrywright This url example.com/?paged3=2&paged1=2&paged2=2 says I am on page 3 of loop 3, page 2 of loop 1 and  page 2 of loop 2. If i go to page 3 of loop 1, my url is example.com/?paged1=3&paged2=2&paged3=2

Answer (score 0):

To set your function up to use classes instead of IDs, which must be unique, do something like this:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul class="page-numbers">
        <li><a class="page-number" href="...">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-number next" href="...">Next »</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$('a.page-number').on('click', function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).closest('.pagination').load(link + ' #pagination ul');
    ...
```

Comment: It's still loading all three containers in all the loops. This is the output - http://i.imgur.com/55GAZNL.jpg